# How to get a music thumbnail in Windows Runtime?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I want to get a music image art, so this is supposed to be the solution:

```
var thumbnail = await musicFile.GetThumbnailAsync(ThumbnailMode.MusicView);
```

But, it only returns a default icon in Windows Phone 8.1 [as it is stated here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storagefile.getthumbnailasync%28v=win.10%29.aspx).

So what to do to get an image for a music file? I see some apps can show it like XBOX Music or OneMusic.

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/805c49e8-f762-4404-8ed6-4cae9dffee04/wp81-storagefilegetthumbnailasync-always-fails?forum=wpdevelop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Known issue with the thumbnails on WP 8.1. The workaround is to emulate what the thumbnail code usually does.

1. Check the folder with the music for an image file, if you find one use that as the thumbnail for all music in the same folder.
2. Manually try and extract an embedded thumbnail using [media foundations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms694197(v=vs.85).aspx)
3. Fallback to the default logo (What the API is returning right now)